# Workaround for soft delete not available in ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

As of now the blob feature 'soft delete' is not yet supported for ADLS Gen2 (hierarchical namespaces turned on). Soft delete is really good for accidental deletes either from human error or programmatic deletion. Considering soft delete is not yet supported for ADLS Gen2, is there any easy workaround for this? We want to really use ADLS Gen2 for its hierarchical namespace feature, but then don't want to lose our data if unintended deletes take place -- similar to soft delete we wan to retain data post its deletion for a few days (e.g. 15 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft Delete for ADLS is now available.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/soft-delete-for-blobs-capability-for-azure-data-lake-storage-is-now-generally-available/

Answer (score 2):

There is no a easy way to mimic the soft-delete feature in ADLS Gen2.

Here are some suggestions you can take a look.

1.Back up all the files to another ADLS Gen2 account. For example, you can create a blob trigger azure function, use [blob storage output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp).

2.Use some tools like [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), periodically copy the files to local.

So when if it was deleted accidentally, just copy it back.